# Action Not Found in project play framework

Tags: angular, playframework

I am new to playframework I would like your help with the following, I defined the following in the routes file

```
GET  /fms/*file              controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/fms/", file )

GET     /alarmas             controllers.AlarmaController.consultaAlarmas
GET     /alarma-detalle      controllers.AlarmaController.detalleAlarma(id_alarma: String ?="null")
GET     /listar-listas       controllers.ListarListasController.consultaListas
POST    /borrar-lista        controllers.ListarListasController.borrarListas
```

When I enter the url http://localhost:9000/fms/index.html the main project works, but if I want to enter any of the other pages it does not work, it generates the error as below,

```
Action Not Found For request 'GET / fms /'
```

How do I make the other links work?

Thanks for your comments

Comment: have you tried the URL without / at the end?

Comment: yes, I tried without the / in the end and it does not work

Comment: What are the other URLs you are trying?

Comment: show the code calling the route `GET /fms/*file` in the project